# Use material color theme in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 7 and Angular Material. I have the following code within my theme.scss file:

```
$web-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-green);
$web-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
$web-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange, A200);

$web-app-theme: mat-light-theme(
  $web-app-primary,
  $web-app-accent,
  $web-app-warn
);

@include angular-material-theme($web-app-theme);
```

Now I want to implement a color theme similar to this with Angular Material:

[image: Material Example]

I've read the documentation for Material color theme creation:
https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation
but I still don't understand how to implement it using Angular.
I want to specify "On Primary", "On Secondary" and so on, but with Angular I've only found ways to define palettes for primary, accent and warn.
Can you give me a hint please, I'm really stuck.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to specify own palettes with custom `contrast` values. Giving a complete overview is rather lengthy so I suggest you read a blog post such as this one [Custom themes with Angular Material](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/05/23/custom-themes-with-angular-material.html).

Comment: So did I understand that correctly that the `contrast` colors in angular material match the `On...` colors? And `foreground` matches `surface`?

Comment: I don't think you can say that it's an exact match. `contrast` is used for text on elements with a given `not contrast` color. For many angular material elements you can specify which color palette (primary, secondary, warn) you want to use. If you don't specify anything `foreground` and `background` is used for components. Don't get to hung up with the terminology used on the official Material Design page. Create your own theme and try it out. If you then have a specific question come back to stackoverflow.

Comment: `contrast`, `foreground` and `background` also aren't just single colors but whole ranges of colors applied under different circumstance. You can check out the [default palette source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/theming/_palette.scss) to see how they're defined.

Comment: @Manuela, what did you end up doing here?